# how can i make my script continuously run

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made the connections in my board where I read the state of a reed switch. When the magnet nearby it shows "0" and I store the data at the "x" variable.

I'm using this to read the state of a fridge door so I can control some relays when the door is open (0) and then turn it off when closed (1).

When I use a while loop, I get the script running but it keeps counting when the variable is 1. I need this script to count when the door opens, (one) closes, and opens again (two).

Here is the code so far with the while loop.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)


inPin=15
outPin=12

GPIO.setup(inPin,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(outPin,GPIO.OUT)

counter = 0

while True:

    x = GPIO.input(inPin)
    previousValue = 0

    print(x)
    if x==1:
        GPIO.output(outPin,GPIO.LOW)
    if x==0:
        GPIO.output(outPin,GPIO.HIGH)
    
    if x == 1 and previousValue == 0:
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
```

Comment: `previousValue` is always `0`. Shouldn't you set it to the value of `x` after you do the check?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the previous value

```py
    if x == 1 and previousValue == 0:
        counter += 1
        print(counter)
        previousValue == 1
    elif x == 0 and previousValue == 1:
        previousValue == 0
```